# Very High Memory Usage on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory-leaks

I've tried to follow this tutorial: [Windows 10 high memory usage (unknown reason)](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason) but to no avail.

I have 8 GB of DRR3 gig ram installed and 6.1 GB are being used right now.

[image]

The processes do not add up. After some Googling I found that link above, but I'm having issues using Poolmon. Poolmon shows this:

[image]

I feel stupid, because I don't know at all how to solve this. Would someone help?

Comment: You are reading to much into what is being reported.  Windows is going to use memory when its not in use, when an application requests it, Windows will provide that application the memory.  The usage you are are seeing is normal, unused idle memory, does not really happen in modern operating systems.  There are numerous questions with really good answers that explain the reasons this is true.

Comment: I booted into safe mode, and restarted it's now staying around 1.7 Gigs. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Oh, another thing I'd like to add is it wouldn't let me post those images. I didn't forget the screenshots.

Comment: install the WPT from Windows 10 SDK (https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), open a cmd.exe as admin and run this: **xperf -on LATENCY+FOOTPRINT+VIRT_ALLOC+MEMINFO+VAMAP+REFSET+MEMINFO_WS+ALL_FAULTS -stackwalk VirtualAlloc+VirtualFree+PROFILE+HardFault+PagefaultTransition+PagefaultDemandZero+PagefaultCopyOnWrite+PagefaultGuard+PagefaultHard+PagefaultAV -buffersize 1024 -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\MemoryUsage.etl** Wait 30s and stop the trace. compress the generated file as 7z/RAR to reduce the size and upload it (OneDrive)

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Comment: any update? Have you looked if your SYSTEM process has a high memory usgae. In tis cause look here: http://superuser.com/a/952142/174557

Comment: I fixed that issue, but now have a issue with super high CPU... I've never had these issues with Windows 7 or 8. I'm a programmer, and use computers very frequently, but I can't figure this issue out.

Comment: what was the cause? Post it as answer. Create a new topic and share a xperf trace of the high CPU usage: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Comment: I never figured out the cause of the memory leak. After a clean boot, and reboot I never had any more issues.

Comment: ok, create a new question and provide the xperf generated file

Comment: Seems that I have a similar problem. In reply to @Ramhound 's first commen, I should have nothing to worry about if task manager is saying 5GB used out of 8GB, and the users tab says I'm only using 2GB?
2GB is not 60% of my total RAM

Comment: @cw1998 - Hard to diagnose a problem through comments.  We were never given enough information to help this user.

Comment: Ok, no problem. If I were to make a new question for my problem, what information should I include to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Bad memory management, as shown in several other topics. Sometimes, a sub-process of svchost causes a memory leak, but that's usually fixable/patchable.