# After upgrading to Windows 10 suddenly low memory issues

Tags: memory, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, memory-management

I have 8GB of ram and a decent computer. After upgrading to Windows 10, I keep getting messages saying I need to close programs and that I am low on memory. Then, right after, my screen will go black and I'll have to restart my computer.

I checked the task manager, I'm using less than 5GB of ram when running visual studio and chrome and various other applications.

So then I tried only running a few tabs in chrome, with non-intensive websites. Same thing. Is this a Windows 10 bug? Because it's happening quite frequently and is extremely annoying.

Comment: It's a really common complaint about Windows 10, usually it's a driver or something similar.  See this [possibly related question](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason) and [this](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-fix-windows-10-high-memory-usage-issue-1514199)

Comment: post pictures of Taskmgr->Perf->Memory, ResMon->Memory and RAMMap: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: @nerdwaller - This problem isn't unique to Windows 10 though.  A driver causing this could happen on any version of Windows.

Comment: @TheRyan722 - Without more information any answer one might submit would be incomplete.

Comment: @Ramhound OP stated this started after an upgrade to Windows 10, many others have experienced this too. Sure it could happen on other versions, but this is the one it is super common on. Absolutely worth validating for the OP, the symptoms match most of the other cases in which this is the fix.

Comment: It validates a broken driver.  I was just pointing out a broken driver is not unique to Windows 10.  It is far to soon to even say its a broken driver without more information.

Comment: again, post some pictures, otherwise we can't answer this