# High Memory Usage Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

[image: process running with high memory usage]

90% memory usage shortly after installing windows 10, I have very little open. My fan has been on full blast for a while now. Kinda [similar to this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason).

But I don't have as high non-paged kernel memory value. I"m going to explore that result for now, can anyone else give me a good idea as to why its so high?

Comment: when I restart my memory usage is back down to a reasonable percentage like 20-30%.

Comment: What's using the CPU? Could be related.

Comment: You've paid for 8GB of RAM. Do you want it go unused? ;)

Comment: what is windows search index do I need to have it running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10, 'System' process taking massive amounts of RAM](http://superuser.com/questions/952141/windows-10-system-process-taking-massive-amounts-of-ram)

Comment: I think the System procress is not the issue here. It’s just an effect of the root cause. Which is probably a search filter. Please [get a list of non-Microsoft search filters](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_filter_view.html) and include it in your question.

Comment: Also related, [a question on Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/the-windows-search-service-consumes-all-available/f8049a31-175a-4715-8317-27f01c06610e)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, the high memory "usage" of the SYSTEM process is [fine and by design](https://superuser.com/a/952142/174557). Instead of paging out data to the page file and (mostly slow HDD), Windows 10 compresses the data and stores it in the SYSTEM process.

[image]

Read my link for a much deeper answer.

To analyze the CPU usage of the Windows search indexer you have to use xperf. Install the WPT (part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk)), open a cmd.exe as admin and run this command:

> xperf -on
>   LATENCY+DISPATCHER+FOOTPRINT+VIRT_ALLOC+MEMINFO+VAMAP+REFSET+MEMINFO_WS
>   -stackwalk VirtualAlloc+VirtualFree+PROFILE+CSwitch+ReadyThread -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\TEMP\HighCPUAndMemoryUsage.etl

If you have enough data of the memory usage grow + CPU usage (1.5 - 3 minutes), press a key to stop tracing.

Open the ETL in WPA.exe and analyze it for [CPU usage](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) and [memory usage grow](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc).

Comment: +1 This behavior is by design. Windows 10 only has two choices, use memory or forever waste it. You can't save memory for later. A machine with 8GB can't use 7GB today so it can use 9GB tomorrow. Any memory not used now is performance forever lost.

Comment: I don’t think this answer applies here. It’s not the System process that’s using all the memory, after all.

Comment: @DanielB I also posted a way to diag memory allocations with xperf. this is a valid answer **rolleyes**

Answer (score 0):

Just after the upgrade to Windows 10, the system re-index all the datas to make the system more efficient.

On computers that hosts a lot of indexable datas, it can take some time.

But when it will be finished, you will get back your memory and performances. the system will only index the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, this command fixed it for me:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to what exactly this find and fixed? How can the OP be sure this will fix their specific problem?

Comment: It fixed some corrupted file that was causing the problem for me, but the scan didn't provide any additional info so I am not sure which file was causing the problem. The search indexer service was consuming almost 20-40% CPU, 2GB+ RAM and 80-100% disk.