# Windows 10 Memory

Tags: windows-10, memory

Every time I'm just using my laptop for a few hours, then all of the sudden my laptop is using 15,6 GB of my RAM. When looking into taskmanager, I can't find the memory back. Adding all of the memory that is being used according to taskmanager is just 3 GB's of RAM. The rest is just missing.

Can someone help me with this? I only have a few programs running: ESET, Razer Synaps, puush, Steelseries Engine 3, NVIDIA GeForce Expreience, Intel Rapid Storage Technologie, Dragon Gaming Center, Ultimate Performance, Nahamic for MSI, Killer Network, MSI True Color, MSI System Controller Manager, Synaptics touchpad, Intel HD Graphics, Skype, Steam, Chrome.

Most of the time I'm watching netflix, playing random games (like Minecraft) or installing games (like Tom Clancy's The Division Beta).

I never had any problems doing this on Windows 7.
I'm using Windows 10 Education.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: When I reboot my system, the RAM goes back to under 3 GB usage.

Comment: Screenshots of where you are seeing this high memory usage are needed. It is normal for Windows to cache a lot of data in RAM and thus appear to have used all your memory when the fact is that the memory will be freed when needed. Otherwise you might have a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: This guy (http://superuser.com/a/957611) seems to suggest that the killer network program w̶a̶s̶ ̶w̶r̶i̶t̶t̶e̶n̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶m̶o̶n̶k̶e̶y̶s̶ ̶ has a memory leak. Disable it booting with Windows and reboot, see if problem re-occurs.

Comment: If all you load is your Nvidia drivers, does this memory problem, still happen?  Use Autoruns to determine this.  Why do you have Intel drivers and Nvidia drivers installed on your system?

Comment: @Ramhound Because it is a MSI laptop. Not a desktop. The Intel HD Graphics is a default driver for my browser.

Comment: @ItsPure rereading what people have said they seem to have had to uninstall the killer network suite entirely and reinstall only the driver package. I'd try the main app itself fist, but don't know if you might have to go for the full uninstall.

Comment: follow my steps (http://superuser.com/a/949246/174557) to see which driver is using too much RAM