# System and Compressed Memory: High Disk Usage

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, memory, compression

System and Compressed Memory is something I had for a long time

Ever since I got this new computer, when starting up my computer, System and Compressed Memory (ntoskml.exe) has been using very high **Disk** usage.

I would like to stop this from happening ever again.

A lot of other people have been having the same problem, but it was either high CPU or Memory usage. I have also searched in the SuperUser Website but I can't find a solution

Could you:

1) Explain what ntoskml.exe is

2) Find a solution to this problem

Specs:

OS: Win 10

Storage: 1TB

RAM: 8GB

Processor: Good enough

**EDIT 1**: A mistake was made, it was ntsk**rnl**.exe not ntsk**ml**.exe I also found out that this happened for only about 10 mins before it went back down

**EDIT 2**: I have used the Windows Performance Recorder to record my system.
Here's the link to download my log: https://www.mediafire.com/?g90g0xp108ptmgx

**EDIT 3**: Im stupid, I recorded it after System and Compressed Memory's disk usage went down. Another link: http://www.mediafire.com/download/foon2og2m7ukl1l/Sytem%26CompressedMemory.zip

Comment: What has Google told you ntoskrnl.exe is? Come on... a bit of your own research wouldn't go amiss!

Comment: I think you have the file name wrong which is why you might be struggling its ntosk R N L.exe not K M L... if you google that with your symptoms you will have more luck... effectively it runs most interactions between software and OS.. most likely causes for resource hogging JAVA!

Comment: @BigChris Google has told me that disabling "Show me tips on Windows" would work. Not true.

Comment: @CharlesH That was just a typo in the post. But thanks for pointing out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 high memory usage (unknown reason)](http://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason)

Comment: @Ramhound Nope, the question you directed me was about High Memory usage. And, the answer did not work for me

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and click to start. Now capture 1 minute of the DiskIO. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: the trace is corrupted. I see no disk activity. Capture the trace again when you see the activity

Comment: I changed the link

Comment: mot IO comes from Avast not system. uninstall it and try a different AV suite. your 5400 WD drive is a large bottleneck. consider buying a SSD Also next time notify my with @my username

Comment: @magicandre1981 Are you sure? This has been happening before I installed avast. At that time, I had Mcafee

Comment: uninstall Avast and share a new trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem

What I did was I uninstalled a bunch of bloatware on my computer, then migrated my account from an online account to a local account. System and Compressed Memory still has a high disk usage but goes down a lot more quicker, in about 2-5 seconds when starting up.

I'd like to thank everyone for their time and patience on this question too, especially magicandre1981 who had taken the time to take a look at my problem.

Still, if you have another answer to this problem, you could answer it here.