# Memory leak from Intel GPU Driver

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics, intel-core-i5, memory-leaks

Thanks to the answer in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason) I found out that my Intel GPU driver is causing memory leak (4.1GB of non-paged pool). I tried to install various versions of driver and this problem comes back every install of drivers. On Windows 10 default driver non-paged pool is 110MB, but when I start installing driver it comes back to 4.1GB (screen goes black for a second during install and it's 4.1GB non-paged pool again). I tried installing driver from Snappy Driver Installer and from official Intel website (Beta 15.40.26.4474, 15.40.25.4463, 15.40.22.4424 i 15.40.10.4300). The result was the exact same every single time.
I was reinstalling the driver in this way:
1. Went to Safe mode
2. Uninstalled driver using Display Driver Uninstaller (from guru3d.com)
3. Restarted to Win 10 normal mode (every time i restarted the non paged pool was about 110MB)
4. Started installation of driver
5. During installation screen went black and non-paged pool was 4.1GB again.

Any thoughts how to fix this?

PS. If this may have something in common with what happens, I reduced my system partition size to 250GB (via Partition Master, because built-in system tool didn't let me reduce this partition as much as I wanted) and soon after graphic driver crashed (screen even didn't go black IIRC, just information about crash showed up). I also updated my drivers via Snappy Driver Installer, but I don't remember if it was before or after the driver's crash.

Comment: I would update all the intel drivers using windows update or intel.com

Comment: Once I didn't blocked automatic update for drivers from Windows Update, Windows installed graphic driver (dedicated to Iris Pro 6200, not just the default one) directly after restart and that driver also had a problem with non-paged pool. The rest of drivers is up-to-date. I updated them via Snappy Driver Installer.

Comment: I have little faith in 3rd party driver updaters.

Comment: I used SDI once or maybe twice to check if it's responsible for this, but all drivers from SDI and Intel website cause the problem. I also wrote the drivers versions i installed from Intel website, so i'm sure that drivers from both sources cause the same problem.

Comment: are you sure it is the Intel driver? Which tag is used? Do you have an ETL file that shows the grow?

Comment: Of course it's not the Intel's driver itself fault, because it happens on various versions of drivers. If system uses default graphic driver, non-paged pool is about 110MB. When system uses Intel's driver, non-paged pool is 4,1GB. Poolmon shows it's @ GMM tag. "findstr /s @ GMM *.*" typed in CMD shows only System32/Drivers/igdkmd64.sys (directly after install, before restart, it shows also temporary directories but there're igdkmd64.sys files and igdkmd64lp.sys files. Do i really need to record installing process to prove that the problem has something in common with using dedicated driver?

Comment: I never saw this leak, so an ETL would be nice so that I can take a look at it

Comment: @magicandre1981 [This file?](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjuImr-X3ciJgjYJV8g8Mins4j5M)

Comment: the allocation is outside the trace, but it is really the . Someone posted the issue 7 months ago: https://communities.intel.com/thread/96869 hope that Intel fixes it

Comment: @magicandre1981 On Polish forum where i also described this problem, i got advice to reset BIOS and then i suddenly recalled that i changed VRAM reserved for iGPU from 448(or something like that)MB to 1GB. I changed it to 512MB and there's no more memory leak. Thank you very much for your help with a problem i created.

Comment: ok, so this high usage came from allocating 4GB to the GPU?

Comment: Not exactly. It seems driver can't allocate more than 512MB of RAM for iGPU. If you choose more than 512MB, there'll be memory leak. When i choosed 1GB, Task Manager showed about 630MB 'Hardware Reservd' memory. Now on 512MB chosen in UEFI Task Manager shows 593MB 'Hardware Reserved'.

Comment: ok. Post your finding as answer with all steps to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was problem with allocating too much RAM to iGPU so driver couldn't handle it. It seems driver cannot allocate more than 512MB VRAM. I wanted more VRAM for games and i created this problem by accident.
I fixed this by going to UEFI, then to "Integrated Peripherals" and i changed RAM assigned to iGPU to 512MB and memory leak disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you using WPF and you change a lot of graphic elements then some graphic drivers have problems (e.g. from Siemens IPCs)

You can solve it with the RegistryKey described here

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201027100953/http://geekswithblogs.net/JeffFerguson/archive/2010/01/24/wpf-video-drivers-and-video-memory-leaks.aspx)

Greetings - Ralf Schiessl, ib-comPLAN

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.