# Windows 10 memory leak after update [Wfpn / ntoskrnl.exe]

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, ntoskrnl.exe, xperf

Notice: I have already read [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason) and followed the steps in it, but I can't figure out what is causing the leak. What I'm looking for here is help in singling out the problem.

As you can see from the title of the question I've encountered a memory leak in Windows 10 after the latest update (Creator's Update I believe). The first thing I did was open the task manager, where I've noticed unpaged memory taking up about 13GB of RAM.

I went through the Poolmon/Pooltag/findstr process only to get garbage on the cmd
[image: output]

I then tried to use Xperf to find out what was happening, but I'm still unsure as to what I'm looking at. The root cause seems to be the kernel image, and I find that hard to believe. Here's the output of Xperf as seen in WPA:
[image: Xperf]

I've had a similar problem in the past on Windows 10 that was caused by Killer Networking drivers, but this time around that doesn't seem to be the culpript.

If anyone is able to help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I state in the first paragraph that this question is different from the one being suggested by the mod (I even link that very question). I had already taken all the steps in the answer to that question and still couldn't track down which driver was causing the issue, hence I was asking for users to help me find which one was the problematic one.

Comment: Have you updated to Version 1703 aka. Redstone 2, aka. Creators Update, Buildno. 15063? Was the update offered to you or did you download the update yourself?

Comment: @wp78de I am currently on version 1703 build 15063.540, yes. I was prompted to restart and update by the system itself, but it appears to be still downloading updates even though their name is the same as the name of the updates I've already installed

Comment: I also experienced a leaking ntoskernel with 1703 with a NUC5, but I also couldn't trace down the root cause. :(

Comment: Could it really be a kernel image memory leak? What would I do in that case?

Comment: The best bet would be a downgrade (at maybe an upgrade to an insider build?) I guess.

Comment: update this bwcW10X64.sys, which look like broadcom network card driver.

Comment: Seems to be killer networking related once again [driver in question](http://www.carrona.org/drivers/driver.php?id=bwcw10x64.sys). I'll update and report back.

Comment: this is a duplicate. as I wrote in my answer look for 3rd party code in the callstack and the bwcW10X64.sys is the only 3rd party file. also an user already posted in the topic that the killer drivers can cause it.

Comment: Did he also say that updating the killer drivers can cause a blue screen? Because that's what's happening to me :/

Comment: such issues are unrelated to the question. I'm out now of this useless discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating the bwcW10x64.sys driver, which is part of the Killer Networking suite.
This is the second time one of their products has caused memory leaks for me on W10, hence if you encounter the same problem and have a KI network card (quite common on gaming motherboards) I suggest you try updating their drivers ASAP.

Edit: watch out because the driver update for KI that came out on 07/08/17 causes blue screen on W10 if the PC is on for more than ~24hrs