# Huge paged pool probably caused by fltMgr.sys , what to do?

Tags: windows, memory, drivers

I found that my Windows machine was using over 95% of RAM constantly and it was often slow.  And I found that "Paged Pool" always used over 10GB RAM.  Here's 2 screenshots of task manager:
[image]

[image]
I followed the instructions in answer https://superuser.com/a/949246/160304  and here's what I found:

- Use poolmon to sort paged pool usage by bytes, the thing which uses around 12GB(I believe) has tag FMfn:
  [image]
- Find out which driver is using tag FMFn, looks like it's fltMgr.sys:
  [image]
- Find out what fltMgr.sys is, it's from microsoft:
  [image]

Now I don't know what to do next. I'd appreciate some ideas.

Comment: Can you explain how you came to this discovery in the first place - before you researched and ran these tools? What does the much more familiar ‘task manager’ or ‘resource monitor’ show for memory usage? Specifically in regards to individual processes?

Comment: I updated my question with 2 more screenshots. I hope that's not too many screenshots.

Comment: It seems you have a hidden process taking a lot of RAM. Try this tool to identify it: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Comment: run the [xperf command from my answer](https://superuser.com/a/949246/174557) and look at the callstack of the FMfn tag. Maybe you also have this WiseFs64.sys usage.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you very much. Yes, I also have Wise folder hider installed.  Removing it solved the problem.