# Memory usage doesn't add up in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance

Every few days of uptime the memory usage of my PC increases without any obvious reason. Here is a typical memory usage reading after 4 days of uptime:

[image: 74% memory usage]

However, I've tried to trace the offending application causing any potential memory leaks. Task Manager lists the highest app usage from Google Chrome (with only ~200MB usage):

[image: Task manager processes]

Closing other apps still leaves 62% mysteriously in use:

[image: 62% memory usage after closing apps]

Meanwhile, `poolmon.exe` shows `CM16` and `Proc` tags are listed using high amounts of memory in the Paged and Nonpaged pools, respectively:

[image: poolmon usage display]

Strangely, restarting the PC clears up memory usage, but shutting down and starting up doesn't. I assume this is due to the "fast startup" feature, but I'm not sure why it would affect memory usage.

If it matters, I am also using [CleanMem](http://www.pcwintech.com/cleanmem) as I assumed it would help alleviate any memory leak problems.

Given these, how could I pinpoint what is causing high memory usage in my system?

UPDATE: I tried to run xperf to view stack traces on the pool tags, as suggested in a comment, but I am not sure what to make of what I have found:

[image: xperf/WPA screenshot of CM31 and Proc tags]

**UPDATE**: [Here is the ETL file of the above screenshot](https://instilledbee.net/stuff/pool.zip)

Comment: I still get ~62% memory usage even without any apps open: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Cp0SHub.png)

Comment: Antivirus shows more memory usage. It does need more RAM.

Comment: @Biswa I am not sure what you mean with needing more RAM? My PC has  8GB installed.

Comment: use [xperf/WPA to analyze the usage of CM16 and Proc tag](https://superuser.com/a/949246/174557)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the tip but I'm not sure what to make of the stack traces. I see ntdll.dll and N/A for some entries.

Comment: Submit the information to pastebin or a similar service.  Be sure you follow the steps Andre already provided in his linked answer

Comment: Is it safe to share the *.etl files publicly? I am concerned about personal information being included in the data.

Comment: the file only includes the names, not the content, so you can share it.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the post with the link to the ETL file.

Comment: next time please notify me with @ myusername. the proc usage in this trace was done by synergyd.exe and syntool.exe. So maybe more commandline tools run all time in background (scheduled tasks). Toke usage comes from all programs doing user permission thinks (Tokens API like ntoskrnl.exe!SepDuplicateToken). Look if the issue is still relevant after updating to 1709, you use Win10 1703.

Comment: When you close all apps what does "cached" say in your performance tab of task manager?  That is just cached disk space so isn't "really used" as it were, FWIW... (for followers "synergyd.exe and syntool.exe" come from the synergy keyboard sharing utility)

Answer (score 4):

From the CleanMem about page:

"The memory is pushed to the system cache, not the page file. The system cache is still in memory. And a program can call back what it needs instantly"

AKA, running "CleanMem" just hides memory behind the system in the cache, so you don't see it being used.

Generally, any kind of "memory management" tool in Windows is a bad idea.

Why? Because especially in an OS as complicated as Windows 10, using some "tweak" to try to get more memory is probably just going to make the existing memory management algorithms get confused. Windows has extremely advanced built-in memory management, compression, caching, and prediction. Don't mess with it. Need to free memory? Use Firefox instead of Chrome.

Also, check out the SysInternalsSuite tool procexp.exe. It is a lot easier to read than xperf:

[image: SysinternalSuiteProcmon.exe]

Another process you may not see using memory would be if you have Hyper-V installed and are running any virtual machines within it.