# High invisible RAM usage

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance, memory-leaks

I have read through a number of threads on this site and run into dead ends which I will attempt to summarize.

The problem: For the last few months I have noticed a very high based RAM usage on my system which is not represented in my Task Manager, RAMmap, or resource monitor. The system reports that approximately half of my 24Gb is in use, but does not show me what processes are using it. I understand that it is normal for the Windows operating system to efficiently use memory by leaving it as "consumed" until it is needed, but certain programs, in particular server hosting, cause my RAM usage to increase dramatically, and my system grinds down to an extreme slowness that makes just using the mouse cursor a laggy chore despite the demanded RAM for the programs loading the system being much lower than my capacity.

As mentioned, I followed advice in several threads on superuser which lead me to try the following:

- Showing all processes in the Task manager: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ege91.jpg
- Using Resource Monitor to view commits: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcJxC.png
- Using RAMmap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huYHa.png
- Following advice from [Windows 10 high memory usage (unknown reason)](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason) , I installed poolmon, Windows Performance Analyzer, and xperf: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBopC.jpg
- I investigated the location and usage of my pagefile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXun1.png
- I checked the behavior of my SSD and HDD with the pagefile on it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRKkN.jpg
- Disabled superfetch in services.
- Used Process Explorer to view Commit Charge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/me60X.png

Nothing seemed particularly alarming, but I have a very untrained eye. I am not sure how to interpret many of the things I posted above, but I do have some observations.

None of the drivers poolmon tracked seemed to be consuming very much, although I am unsure of what normal values are. In WPA, expanding the stack yielded little to no information, as can be seen above. I looked around a little and did not see anything shocking. I am out of ideas for what else could be causing this memory leak and am happy to provide system information, specs, etc.

Comment: Your RAMMap image shows 10GB unused. It's not easy for us to figure out the problem if we don't have data from the time you were having a problem. If you're having slowness with 10GB RAM unused, your performance problem likely has nothing to do with RAM usage!

Comment: You might try Intelligent standby list cleaner, which helps put memory back into use. https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/intelligent-standby-list-cleaner-v1000-released

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The utility works, but all it does is free up cache memory. Although this was around 5GB, it had no impact on the base state of the system: https://i.imgur.com/jwyWEPH.png