# Non paged pool ConT consumes a lot of memory

Tags: windows-10, memory-leaks

I have in my PC 16GB of memory.
If I leave my computer on for some time (hours or days, it is random), at some point I get a 90% load of memory and I get a lot of apps being really slow for some time (1 minute - forever, again random, some times I need to reboot). Even if the apps continue to run normally the memory usage is still pretty high (over 70%).

[image: Memory Monitor]

I followed the instructions from this [post](https://superuser.com/a/949246/257240) and used ***poolmon*** to check all non paged usages of memory in the pool and found out that there is **a single allocation of 5GB by ConT**, while the next one allocates only 35MB.

[image: Poolmon]

According to the post, we assume that there is a driver with a memory leek. So, I tried to find the driver using: `findstr /m /l /s ConT %Systemroot%\System32\drivers\*.sys`

[image: Find ConT]

I found nothing.
Then I starting searching for more information about ConT and found [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2009/06/23/pool-tag-list/) that it stands for: **Contiguous physical memory allocations for device drivers**, and there is no specific driver that is connected with it.

***Can you help me find out how to reduce the memory it allocates and make my PC fast again?***

Comment: I think I have a non paged pool problem.  I see one computer where Cont is the highest, but it's only 40 megs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConT seems to be linked to my **VirtualBox**. It allocates the memory needed by my VMs. This is the reason it is so high. As soon as I shutdown my VM, I see the memory being freed instantly. While my VMs allocate memory dynamically, they seem to never free memory that they have allocated, until rebooting them. So, I guess ***every now and then I need to reboot my VMs***.

Also ***I decreased the memory assigned to my VMs*** and this helped a lot, because there is a limit on how much memory they can allocate and the freezes of my PC do not happen as often now.