# Windows Embedded 7 Memory Leak - Tag (poolmon) TD - Nonpaged Pool High Usage

Tags: memory, windows-embedded-7

I've been dealing with a memory leak and have been researching what the culprit is using Poolmon, Xperf and Windows Performance Analyzer.
The SO is a Windows Embedded 7 - 32 bit: I think that the nominal nonpaged pool limit is very low, maybe 256 MB (can't find the actual limit, after 200/250 MB I have problems with my C# software).

I've found that the processes with the Poolmon tag 'TD' use most of the nonpaged pool:
I've tried to search for this TAG in

- C:\Windows\System32\drivers
- C:\Windows\SysWow64\drivers
- C:\Program Files

but unsuccessfully.
For this research I followed [this post](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/general/troubleshooting-nonpaged-and-paged-pool-errors-in-windows).

This is the Poolmon image:

[image: Poolmon image]

After generating a `pool.etl` file using xperf, I opened it in WPA and located the non-paged processes using this unknown tag. I found the processes, but they are both 'Unknown' processes according to WPA:

[image: WPA image]

Here is the [link to pool.etl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14jx3tvChLtkN3xuCAbmRKcDs7GZZaUGY/view?usp=sharing).

For this analysis, I followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason/949246#949246) post
and I used this command:

```
xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+POOL -stackwalk PoolAlloc+PoolFree+PoolAllocSession+PoolFreeSession -BufferSize 2048 -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\pool.etl
```

Any suggestions?
Where do I take it from here and what can I do?