# Huge unjustified memory usage

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have already checked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason?newreg=65a21fdd34ab49ce8ff81c39b62cd194) question on memory leaks. In that case, the guy had a huge non-paged memory and very little paged, which led everyone to the conclusion that he had a memory leak from one of his drivers. I don't know if that's the case for me.

In my case, I have a huge unjustified memory usage.

I have a total of 24GB of RAM that came preinstalled with my Asus ROG Strix laptop. All the time, there's like 22GB of RAM used out of these. I have no idea how this happens. The laptop was cleaned 3 months ago for dust, so it's *probably* not a dust problem.

[image]

[image]

Also, my SSD is not corrupted. I *think* I just don't have one.

My computer is really laggy as of recent and I really wonder why.

Comment: Just to make it clear.  The fact machine is dust free would have not impact on the amount of memory that is used.  How large is your page file?

Comment: Total paging file size for all drivers: 22528MB (from Advanced tab of Performance of System Properties)

Comment: You didn't provide us very many of your processes but your memory usage is indicating that all your physical and virtual memory has been committed, that typically means, you are running a massive program or you have a memory leak.  Given your CPU usage is 37% you are likely NOT running a massive program.

Comment: So what is your actual issue? That your RAM is being used to its intended maximum is not an issue. That's what it's there for. To expect it to be always 'empty' is like buying a party balloon & never inflating it. Sure, it will last forever that way, but will never fulfil its intended purpose.

Comment: @Tetsujin The problem is that the Memory used to be at around 10-15% a few months ago and now it's constantly at 95%. More than often I can barely use Firefox to navigate the internet, and I suppose that's a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I was running Firefox and Discord at the time of taking the prtsc. Do I just go through the steps for the poolmon scans and then go from there?

Comment: RAM usage is a benefit, not a punishment. Quit your browser to check for the most obvious source of usage, reboot to clear.

Comment: I did that, even with all the programs closed it still takes up 87% of the memory looking at the Processes tab (with windows processes only), and Antimalware Service Executable takes up the most, which is 120MB

Comment: Did which? Reboot will clear all, then you monitor what is used as you relaunch your memory hogs, like browsers. On my own machine I can see top usage on web pages, several needing 3, 4, 500MB each. It soon adds up.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I don't disagree unused memory is pointless, however, I would expected a great deal more to be in (standby or available) memory.  The usage if I am reading it right is indicating something is eating all the author's virtual memory ( 22.5 GB) and nearly 22 GB of the system memory leaving around 1.5 GB free for later use.  To me the usage indicates a memory leak, but if the usage is that high immediately after a reboot, that would be one heck of a memory usage (or something silly like a 16 GB VM automatically being restarted)

Comment: Have you done a thorough virus scan with a tool *other* than your regular antivirus? Also, in Task Manager | Details  add Working Set (Memory) and sort on that.

Comment: Okay, I did a clean reboot, and now I notice that with only Firefox open and task manager and resource monitor I'm sitting at a constant 18% (4.2GB in use). 

I sorted on Working memory now and it's exactly like I expected: firefox.exe is first with 0.3GB. 

Now that it's constantly 18%, it must mean that there's a memory leak in a program I usually use? Or is it something else?

Comment: It could be a one-off memory leak, something crashing and running away. Difficult to know unless it happens repeatedly. Reboots are a useful diagnostic tool  to figure out if something just crashed or if the problem is repeatable.

Comment: Then it must be something I use on a daily basis. So far I've already tried Firefox, Discord, X2Go (VM for uni work), GeForce Experience, Steam and some games. I will update my question as soon as I find what was causing it. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: A modern daily shutdown is no longer the same as a proper reboot. Shotdown may close programs, but the core of the OS is hibernated so if there is a driver fault or a program that is leaking kernel memory then it will persist. A reboot will properly start from scratch.

Comment: I genuinely did not know that. That's some really good info.