# Windows 11 ALL memory used and does not get released when programs closed

Tags: memory, windows-11

Did not notice this issue after upgrading to Windows 11 a couple of months back, but recently my RAM was 99% used several times and remained at 99% used even after closing all running programs other than background apps. Needless to say, computer became unresponsive and I had to reboot to return RAM usage back to normal.

Here is the Task Manager screenshot:

[image: Task Manager]

I opened up the Resource Monitor and none of the running tasks were using inordinate amount of memory:

[image: Resource Monitor]

I fired up Sysinternals Process Explorer and it did not provide any additional clues:

[image: Process Explorer]

Process Explorer Sys Info provided more details than Resource Monitor but still nothing gave me a clue what exactly is happening here and what is taking up all that memory:

[image]

Any idea how to figure out what exactly is eating up all that RAM when this happens next time?

- Windows 11 Version 21H2 (OS Build 22000.469)
- MSI MEG X570 Unify with latest BIOS and AMD ComboAm4v2PI 1.2.0.5
- 32 GB of RAM

Comment: Use MS Config to start with selective / minimal startup. Restart and then start adding your regular apps to see what is causing the issue. It is not a Windows 11 issue (two Windows 11 machines here). You may need to Repair Windows 11.

Comment: Your running some applications that is not only requesting memory to be used, but keeping it, leaving your system with virtually no memory.  Are you running a VM of any type by chance? The only thing it might be is a memory leak within a driver. That’s where using minimal startup will come in handy

Comment: @Ramhound No VM used... if some app is keeping RAM in use why is that not visible in the list of processes neither in Task Manager or Process Explorer?

Comment: That is why I suggest minimal boot and adding apps to see what is happening. It all the memory is used with minimal apps, then time to repair or even reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is that I have no reliable way of reproducing this. It happens once in a while regardless of what programs are running...

Comment: [You will have to use poolmon to diagnose a memory leak.](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason/949246#949246). I would say the conclusion to that possible duplicate applies to your case given your using 30 GB of non-paged RAM

Comment: no ....way of reproducing this. It happens once in a while regardless of what programs are running...   ....  If if does not matter what is running, you should strongly consider backing up and reinstalling Windows.'

Comment: @John - And if I it’s a driver to blame, they will just install the same drivers, and have the same problem on a clean install of Windows

Comment: Possible about a driver, but a new install with no apps should not use memory like this. Unless the machine has faulty drivers as you suggest.  I actually have not seen a faulty driver issue like this.

Comment: A WHQL signed driver so abhorrent that it eats up 30+ GB of ram is highly HIGHLY unlikely but the fact that it isn't showing up in the process list is indeed a puzzler.

Comment: On Windows 10, I've found Wagnardsoft's *Intelligent standby list cleaner*, https://www.wagnardsoft.com/ISLCw , helpful with memory-intensive tasks, such as processing many files in Calibre at once, though it was originally developed to improve RAM issues in games. It's free and worth a try -- hopefully it's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I just caught the culprit and it is [PowerToys Always On Top](https://news.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-powertoys-gets-always-on-top-feature-106619/) feature. I noticed my computer was slow and opened the Task Manager to find PowerToysAlwaysOnTop process using some CPU time and although the memory used was displayed as 1 MB as soon as I killed it my memory used dropped from 98% to 18%.

I disabled that feature of PowerToys and will update this reply if memory leak happens again while the feature is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Any updates?  i have the same problem, but don't have the "Always On Top" powertoy turned on.